# when can java client receive -1 from c server?

Tags: java, c, sockets

My client is writen in java. The server is written in C.
When the client read from the server, the read function return -1.
I kown in java if the outputstream closed before the socket closed, java client will receive -1. but when in C, when the java client will receive -1?

```
JAVA CASE:
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(buf);
out.close();
out.write(otherbuf);
```

In this case the when the client call read() it will return -1.

If server is writen in c, when the java client will return -1??
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What language the server is written in is irrelevant. It could be written in anything, the client does not know and should not care (in general).

A `read` will return `-1` when it reaches the end of stream, as documented. The end of stream happens when the other side closed that side of the (TCP) socket.

(On the C side, assuming a POSIX system, the socket can be closed either with the `close(2)` system call, or with the `shutdown(2)` system call. The later allows the program to only close one "side" of the connection, i.e. close the write side but keep the read side open. `close` shuts both sides down.)

Comment: Thank you. I missed the read and write function. If you write a closed socket fd, you'll receive a broken pipe signal(SIGPIPE). But if you read a closed socket, read returns -1, and set the errno to be EBADF. Thank you again.

Comment: @xaioming that's not correct. If you write to a broken *connection* you will get EPIPE or SIGPIPE depending on your signal configuration. If you read from a closed connection it will return zero. If you read or write a socket you have closed yourself you will get -1 and EBADF.